# extend other app to my template working

Tags: django

I want to extend an other template to my blog.html, no matter have i try to extend this, it doesn`t work .
blog/index.html

```
{% block nav %}
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>{% block nav-blog %}<a href="/blog/">Blog</a>{% endblock %}</li>
        <li>{% block nav-photo %}<a href="/photo/">Photo</a>{% endblock %}</li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
<div class="news">
    {% block polls %}   
        {% extends 'polls/index.html' %}
    {% endblock %}
<div>
```

polls/index.html

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually extends has to be stuck at the top of the template and not somewhere in the template. 
In the template you use the tags that you have set up in the base templates.

Comment: yes thats right, but if i put on top of the page it doesn`t display it too

Comment: hmm, then make sure that you can access the template Without extending it, and also make sure that you have these template paths  set up properly in the settings file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're doing two things here:

1. Declare a "nav" block in your index.html.  This will let django know the part of your index html you wish to have overwritten when a template `extends` it.  Anything you put inside the "nav" block in index html will be considered default content.
2. You need to use the "extends" template tag at the beginning of your blog.html so django knows the template you'd like to extend.

Like this:

`index.html`

```
{% block nav %}
  <div>
     Some default html here..
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And then `blog.html`

```
{% extends index.html %}    
{% block nav %}
  <div>
     This is what will render
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Also, you're going to want to test `index.html` before trying to extend it to verify that django is finding that template.  If it isn't then you need to add the directory that it is found in to the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` array in your `settings.py` file.